# script to auto move a folder with movie file

Tags: autocomplete, directory

I have a download folder that is the destination for all torrent download files. I want a script which monitors that folder and then automatically only copy, moves the complete folder containing the movie file (mkv,avi,mp4...etc) and ignores everything else in the download folder. Is it possible

Thanks and Regards
Sammy

Answer (score 0):

Which scripting language would you like to use? What OS are you on? It is quite possible, and if you chose Python as your scripting language, you would be able to find many useful scripts that do what you want.

Comment: Apologies I missed to give other details. I am using windows 10. I can use shell script, or a batch file that can run some dos command to achieve the same. I can use python as well, but in that case I would need complete script as I do not know python very well.